# Kafka Chart on Kubernetes: Simple test string produce + consume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I install the incubator Kafka chart. Version `kafka-0.8.5` as of this writing.

```
helm install --name kafka \
  --set replicas=1 \
  --set persistence.enabled=false \
  --set zookeeper.replicaCount=1 \
  incubator/kafka
```

To try this out I run a separate pod as just a bash shell with Kafka cli tools. I'm using the exact same Docker image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.1-2` that the `kafka-0` pod is using so that there is a perfect version match between the client and server:

```
kubectl run shell --rm -i --tty --image confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.1-2 -- /bin/bash
```

Listing topics, publishing messages, getting topic offsets all works perfectly, as shown below. However, when I try to run `kafka-console-consumer` and see the test record in the topic, it hangs indefinitely. Why?

```
root@shell-5c6ddf5d99-tbsvm:/# /usr/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper kafka-zookeeper:2181 --list

__confluent.support.metrics

root@shell-5c6ddf5d99-tbsvm:/# echo "abcxyz" | /usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test-topic

>[2018-08-07 16:43:26,110] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

root@shell-5c6ddf5d99-tbsvm:/# /usr/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper kafka-zookeeper:2181 --list

__confluent.support.metrics
test-topic

root@shell-5c6ddf5d99-tbsvm:/# /usr/bin/kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic test-topic --time -1

test-topic:0:1

root@shell-5c6ddf5d99-tbsvm:/# /usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --from-beginning --topic test-topic

<hangs indefinitely>
```

FYI, this is a local minikube development cluster with the latest minikube with Kubernetes 1.10.x server-side and 1.10.x kubectl client tools. This is a clean, new minikube, with nothing else running besides kafka, kafka-zookeeper, and my shell pod.

Also, writing a small Java client test app to consume gets a similar result of polling indefinitely with no messages. When my Java client subscribes to `test-topic`, it never gets notification callbacks of being assigned to the one topic partition.

Comment: Might be worth checking out - https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator

Comment: Thanks! These official Confluent Helm Charts just came out to the public: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts so I'll check those out next.

Answer (score 2):

This cost me hours myself, there's a [bug in minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1568) which prevents Kafka from working.

I'm not familiar with the Helm deployment, but you have to make sure of two things. First, the Kafka advertised host has to be the same as your Kubernetes service IP (or DNS name in kube dns), and second, you have to put minikube's network interface in promiscuous mode:

```
minikube ssh sudo ip link set docker0 promisc on
```

If you don't do this workaround, kafka can't contant itself via the Kubernetes service, and its leader election fails. I've found it to be very fragile inside a container deployment environment.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work... 

I'm familiar with the issue you cite, where pods can do a DNS name resolution of other services but fail when attempting a DNS name resolution of their own service. That's confused me in the past. Pods can still access themselves by, for example, `curl $(hostname -s).$(hostname -d):9092`.

Next, I find it odd, that producing a message seems to work, listing topics works, but consuming messages doesn't work.

Comment: You can try this. Set the environment variable `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME` to the IP address of the Kafka service. This makes kafka accept connections and talk to itself via that IP, and where the minikube bug plays in. If you use the local hostname, that's the Pod IP, which isn't one where Kafka is reachable by others, so it won't work from outside the kafka pod.

Comment: The Kubernetes pod command already includes `export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://${POD_IP}:9092`

Comment: `${POD_IP}:9092` is wrong. You need the service IP as the advertised hostname.

I'm not sure how Helm does it, I spun it up by writing manifests by hand. If you ever need anyone outside the pod to reach Kafka, you must have a Kubernetes Service defined for it, and the advertised hostname must be set to that IP.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but that only involves providing access to outside the cluster... From within the cluster, using the pod IP is fine, and that's where I'm experiencing the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't get that part. We don't know why the messages are going missing - we need to find out. You need to look at the logs in the pods and see if there are any errors. Without those, it's hard to say. When the consumer hangs like that. it's usually a connectivity issue, though.

As a first test - telnet to the kafka host and port instead of using the consumer, does it connect?

Comment: I agree that hangs are likely connection issue. Within the cluster I can absolutely do basic TCP test. I used curl instead of telnet even though these services are not HTTP just to verify that the TCP connection is working. kafka:9092 and kafka-zookeeper:2181 both work fine from my cli pod inside the cluster. Also, I clearly can connect since I can list topics, publish a message, query that the message exists, I just can't consume it. I suspect there is some more complex handshake type process that experiences a connection failure that I can't see from the surface.